# Exposed filter render as autocomplete but I need a select field

Tags: 6, views

I have a moderation queue that uses these filters:

- published: no
- content type: xxxx
- author uid: EXPOSED

Drupal renders the exposed filters as auto-complete, but I need to use a select field. Is it possible?

Comment: Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16517124/1072114) for exactly same question on StackOverflow (it's for D7 though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an advance solution.  Checkout how this guy did it for a similar problem by creating his own view filter. [Creating custom filters in views 2](http://zugec.com/drupal/creating-custom-filters-in-views-2)